# cannot find module '@babel/generator' but it installed

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

i have " cannot find module '@babel/generator' " error while trying generate signed apk.
But i installed this package using yarn add, this is part of my package.json:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.17.6",
    "@babel/generator": "^7.17.9",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^7.16.8",
```

and my package lock json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@ampproject/remapping": "^2.1.0",
    "@babel/code-frame": "^7.16.7",
    "@babel/generator": "^7.17.9",
```

and many match when i use ctrl+f in package.lock.json and search babel/generator

Answer (score 3):

I received the same error when i was trying to install the dependencies of my project.

### Solution:

- Delete the `node_modules` **folder** of the project
- Remove the `yarn.lock` or `package.lock` **file** from your project
- Install the dependencies again,  by using `yarn` or `npm install` command.

The above steps fixed my error with the @babel/generator.

Comment: I was able to use this solution to get past the babel generator error with only steps 2 & 3. I did not need to delete the `node_modules` folder for the project.

Answer (score 0):

Simply delete the `node_modules` folder and re-install all the packages by running `npm install` or `yarn install`.

If the error persists, simply install the `@babel/generator` package to your project or globally.

Check out the package and installation guide [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/generator)

Comment: i did, but problem not solved

Comment: Check my edited answer

Comment: unfortunately still not fixed

Answer (score 0):

in my case it solved by this command

```
yarn install --check-files
```

and then **restart the dev server**
Verifies that already installed files in node_modules did not get removed
Good luck